# Jquery works only on first forloop element?

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-selectors, django-templates

Here is my Django template:

```
{% for feed in feeds %}
    <div id="feed"><b>At {{feed.location}}:<b> {{feed.msg}}</b></div></br>
    <button id="bb{{feed.id}}">Add Comment</button>
    <div id="commentbox" style="display:none;">
      <form method="post" action="/comment/{{feed.id}}/">
        {{cform.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="comment" />
      </form>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Jquery code is here:

```
<script>
    $(function() {


          $("#bb.").click(function () {
          $("#commentbox").toggle("slow");
          });

    });
</script>
```

But here only the first div toggles inside the for loop. Jquery does not work for the remaining for loop elements. Can you please give me the proper jQuery code. Thanks.

Comment: You should never have more than one element with any given id. Ids are supposed to be unique; repeating them is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I have changed the ids yet I the same prob. Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make this change:

```
<button class="bb" id="bb{{feed.id}}">Add Comment</button>
<div class="commentbox" style="display:none;">
```

and this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bb").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function () {
      $(this).next().toggle("slow");
    });
  });
});
```

Update:
And here is [a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tesbh/).

Answer (score 3):

As Tikhon suggests, using duplicate ID's is asking for trouble. Add a class to these elements and use a jQuery selector based on the class and you should be fine. Something like,

```
{% for feed in feeds %}
<div id="feed"><b>At {{feed.location}}:<b> {{feed.msg}}</b></div></br>
<button class="bb" id="bb{{feed.id}}">Add Comment</button>
<div class="commentbox" style="display:none;">
  <form method="post" action="/comment/{{feed.id}}/">
    {{cform.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="comment" />
  </form>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and

```
<script>
$(function() {
      $(".bb").click(function () {
          $(this).next('.commentbox').toggle("slow");
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: now all the forloop element get toggled no matter which element button is pressed.

Comment: +1 This is better than mine: no need for `.each()` (that I used), and more specific `next()` selector, besides, it has been posted while I was still writing mine. @Nazim: Please feel free to re-accept the better solution (and I encourage you to).